# What open-source video editors are available with 4k capabilities?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor, hd-video

Are there any open-source video editors available for Ubuntu that have 4k exportation capabilities?

If not, are there any proprietary (free or paid) license video editors with these skills?

Comment: I will accept an answer the day before the bounty expires, just in case something amazing appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Blender** has an integrated Video Sequencer and supports 4K cinema resolution, 
a proof of that is that Sintel, a movie produced with blender, is available for download in 4K :)

http://www.blendernation.com/2011/02/20/sintel-4k-available/

*More information about Blender here:*

http://www.blender.org/

You can obviously install Blender from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Lightworks will be available for ubuntu next month.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/oscar-winning-video-editor-lightworks-landing-on-linux-in-october

[Lightworks running on Ubuntu](http://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=19&id=22049&Itemid=81)

Comment: I myself cannot wait to see it! AFAIK 4K is for the pro version only.

Comment: The pro version should be $60. However no pricing was available for the alpha release.

Comment: Only $60? That's a really good deal. *off-topic*. Anyway, welcome to Ask Ubuntu and I hope you will be around for some time.

Answer (score 2):

Openshot, Shotcut,and Kdenlive now support the editing and export of 4K videos.

- Among them, the fastest editor should be [Shotcut](https://www.videoproc.com/video-editor/shotcut-review.htm) as it allows
  you to create optimized media and take utilization of GPU
  acceleration.
- [Kdenlive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129328/how-do-i-control-output-video-) is stable on Linux system, but temporarily not quite
  stable on Windows.And it doesn't support GPU acceleration and multi
  core CPU processing.
- [Openshot](https://www.capterra.com/p/173466/OpenShot-Video-Editor/) is buggy and more basic.

  file-size-with-kdenlive

Answer (score 1):

You can try using cinelerra. It is said to have support for 4k videos since August 2004. <sup>[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinelerra#History)</sup>

To install do these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Shotcut (http://www.shotcut.org/bin/view/Shotcut/Features). I haven't tried 4k-Videos it but it says the recent version supports it.

Answer (score 1):

also have a look at http://lumiera.org/ ... still under development

Comment: You could add some basic instructions about how to install and use the tool you recommend and describe its important features to improve the quality of your answer.